# ModuleNotFoundError with setup.py/easy_install, but pip works

Tags: python, windows, pip, setuptools

I am developing an application and would like to put it into the active venv using "setup.py develop". This does not work correctly; Python does not find the installed dependencies afterwards.

If I build a wheel from it and install that with pip, everything works fine.

Abridged installation log below. The full output is quite a bit longer, but it is just one package after another getting installed successfully.

```
C:\Daten\pyv>py -3.7-32 -m venv v37-32

C:\Daten\pyv>v37-32\Scripts\activate

(v37-32) C:\Daten\pyv>cd ..\Projekte\i\IB4Application

(v37-32) C:\Daten\Projekte\I\IB4Application>python setup.py develop
running develop
Checking .pth file support in C:\Daten\pyv\v37-32\Lib\site-packages\
C:\Daten\pyv\v37-32\Scripts\pythonw.exe -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: C:\Daten\pyv\v37-32\Lib\site-packages\ appears to support .pth files
```

[...]

```
Installed c:\daten\projekte\i\ib4application
Processing dependencies for IB4Application==1.0
Searching for PyQt5<6
```

[...]

```
Installing PyQt5-5.11.3-5.11.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win32.whl to c:\daten\pyv\v37-32\lib\site-packages
writing requirements to c:\daten\pyv\v37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5-5.11.3-py3.7-win32.egg\EGG-INFO\requires.txt
Adding PyQt5 5.11.3 to easy-install.pth file
```

[... mountains of dependencies ...]

```
Searching for PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.11
```

[...]

```
Installing PyQt5_sip-4.19.13-cp37-none-win32.whl to c:\daten\pyv\v37-32\lib\site-packages
Adding PyQt5-sip 4.19.13 to easy-install.pth file
```

[... mountains of dependencies ...]

```
Finished processing dependencies for IB4Application==1.0
```

---

Now that the installation is complete, I move out of the project path to avoid accidental relative imports.

```
(v37-32) C:\Daten\Projekte\I\IB4Application\IB4Application>cd ..\..
```

I run the wrapper script that the installation created so I get the error messages.

```
(v37-32) C:\Daten\Projekte\I>python ..\..\pyv\v37-32\Scripts\IB4Application-script.pyw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\daten\projekte\i\ib4application\IB4Application\main.py", line 17, in main
    from . import app
  File "c:\daten\projekte\i\ib4application\IB4Application\app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

The same error happens if I `import PyQt5.sip` directly in the REPL.

The venv's site-packages directory looks like this (without all the other dependencies):

```
2018-11-02  19:37               420 easy-install.pth
2018-11-02  19:37               126 easy_install.py
2018-11-02  19:37                37 IB4Application.egg-link
2018-11-02  19:37    <DIR>          pip
2018-11-02  19:37    <DIR>          pip-10.0.1.dist-info
2018-11-02  19:37    <DIR>          pkg_resources
2018-11-02  19:37    <DIR>          PyQt5-5.11.3-py3.7-win32.egg
2018-11-02  19:37    <DIR>          PyQt5_sip-4.19.13-py3.7-win32.egg
2018-11-02  19:37    <DIR>          setuptools
2018-11-02  19:37    <DIR>          setuptools-39.0.1.dist-info
```

Note that `setup.py` installed all the wheels as eggs. `easy-install.pth` has:

```
c:\daten\projekte\i\ib4application
./pyqt5-5.11.3-py3.7-win32.egg
./pyqt5_sip-4.19.13-py3.7-win32.egg
```

The missing module is at `./pyqt5_sip-4.19.13-py3.7-win32.egg\PyQt5\sip.pyd`, exactly where it belongs in this environment.

If I start with a blank venv and install a pre-made wheel of the application using pip, it installs the dependencies in "dist-info" style and the relevant part of site-packages looks like this instead:

```
2018-11-02  19:56    <DIR>          PyQt5
2018-11-02  19:56    <DIR>          PyQt5-5.11.3.dist-info
2018-11-02  19:56    <DIR>          PyQt5_sip-4.19.13.dist-info
```

Running the application now works, but without the special features of `setup.py develop`.

I tried running Python under procmon to see whether it was actually looking inside the egg directories, and found that while it is going through the entries in `easy-install.pth` when looking for `PyQt5.sip`, it is apparently a bit confused because it tries to open a file named "<stdin>" in each of the directories. Each time that fails, it tries the next egg. This also proves that the error is not due to missing dependencies of the DLL because Python never even tries to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but at least a workaround. I just found out about `pip install -e .`, and of course, it works.